# consecutively multiplying the elements of a list with another list python

Tags: python

I'm new to python and my problem is most likely very easily solved, but I couldn't figure it out and I couldn't find any topics that matched my specific issue. 
I have 2 lists of numbers in python: Eg.
    `a=[0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04]`
    `b=[0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05]`
I would like to multiply every element in list "a" with all the elements from list "b" and produce ,in this case, 4 new lists: 
    `a0=a[0]*b`
    `a1=a[1]*b`
    `a2=a[2]*b`
    `a3=a[3]*b`
What is the best way to do that?

Comment: What exactly does `a[0]*b` mean here? Would `2*[1,0]` be `[2,0]` or `[1,0,1,0]`?

Answer (score 2):

It can be `[[x * y for y in b] for x in a]`

Or `[x * y for x in a for y in b]` if you want a flattened result

Comment: I think the question is unclear. The original asnwer you posted might be the correct one

Answer (score -1):

Does this do what you want? Hope it helps :)

```
for element in a:
    for i in range(len(b)):
        b[i] = b[i] * element
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I've tried something similar, but  it doesnt really work for me, because the elements in both list i'm using are floats.